# Change model as user types into a custom Angular directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm just learning Angular and wanted to try out making a simple directive in my project.

It's basically just an input surrounded with some mark up with some styling.

text-input.html:

```
<div class="form-group row">
<label class="col-sm-2 form-control-label">{{label}}</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
    <input name="{{input}}" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="{{placeholder}}"/>
</div>
```

I'm using it like this

```
<text-input ng-model="newBookCtrl.bookConfig.title" label="Title" input="title" model="newBookCtrl.bookConfig.title" placeholder="Title"></text-input>
<text-input ng-model="newBookCtrl.bookConfig.modOrigin" label="Module Origin" input="modOrigin" model="newBookCtrl.bookConfig.modOrigin" placeholder="e.g. http://blah.org"></text-input>
```

Where newBookCtrl is a controller that just has a single JavaScript object called bookConfig.

The text-input directive:

```
    app.directive("textInput", function(){
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
            label: "@",
            input: "@",
            placeholder: "@",
        },
        templateUrl: "/static/book_config/html/text-input.html",
        link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs, ngModelController){
            var input = iElement.find("input")
            ngModelController.$render = function(){
                input.val(ngModelController.$viewValue);
            };
            scope.$watch(function(){return input.val();}, function(newVal, oldVal){
                if (newVal !== oldVal){
                    ngModelController.$setViewValue(input.val());
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

So what happens is that the bookConfig model object only gets updated when you press **Enter**. However, I'd like to update the model whenever the value within the textbox is changed without requiring **Enter** to be pressed.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by creating a two way binding with the actual model. And you should not need to do what you are doing in your link function with $render and $watch. Try this in your directive

```
 scope: {
        label: "@",
        input: "@",
        placeholder: "@",
        ngModel:"="
    },
```

And this in the template

```
   <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input ng-model="ngModel" name="{{input}}" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="{{placeholder}}"/>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try when I get the chance. Why doesn't ngModel in the template require brackets?

Comment: The brackets (interpolation) are meant to tell angular to evaluate the expression inside. But it is not required with standard angular js attributes like ng-model, ng-repeat etc. Angular does that automatically..